# Using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to populate n-to-n relationship

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I have a script file, that is downloading images for products in my database. The products on which the file is working are stored in a `Products` table. Each row in the table (ie, each product), may have 1 or more images that needs to be downloaded.

Until now, the downloaded images were stored in a separate table, named `ProductImages`, where each downloaded image were connected to a single product from the product database via a foreign key. The `ProductImages` table were storing the path to the downloaded image file, and besides that, some meta information about the image that was downloaded.

We realized, that we have other images also, which needs to be stored in the database, besides images for products, so I am trying to separate the information relating to the images from the `ProductImages` table, to a separate `Images` table, which in turn will be connected back to the `Product` table, via a relational table.

My problem lies in the addition of the downloaded images and their data to the database. To make things faster, rows in the `ProductImages` table were inserted to the database in batches, with a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` call: my script knew and knows which image belongs to which product, so I build a CSV file from the data in the scripts memory, then load that file into the database.

But with the new database structure, I would first need to load the image information in it's separate table (where MariaDB will assign a unique, autoincrementing primary key to each image), then populate the relational table with relations between `Products` and `Images`. The problem is that I will not know in advance the primary keys that are beign associated to each inserted image, thus I can not populate the relational table in this way any more.

My only idea was to insert a helper column to the `Images` table, a unique id generated by my downloader script, which can be used to populate the relations, but this seems a bit dirty to me. Is there any other way in which I can keep using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and populate the relational table also?